# How to I achieve "What's the Pic" iPhone app like brick animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to know who to achieve falling blocks animation, the way they do in What Pic app
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/whats-pic-guess-word-hiding/id600716806?mt=8

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean animation, when block is falling down and rotating, you can use [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) property of `UIView` like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 20);
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
             animations:^{
                 view.transform = transform;
             }];
```

If you want to have exactly the same animation, you can use [animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) to add some options to your animation

Answer (score -1):

..or you can save your effort altogether and get a ready-made starter kit from others who did the same thing such as yourself

http://www.sellmyapplication.com/source-code/whats-the-pic-starter-kit/